# Prevent direct manipulation of html5 input number field

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

I created an html5 input number field as follows:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="51" value="1"/>
```

Now I want the user to be able to cycle through the numbers using the up and down arrow buttons. However I don't want the user to be able to directly enter a new number in the field. How do I do this?

I tried setting `readonly="true"`, but as expected, that also disabled the user's ability to cycle through the numbers using the up and down arrow buttons.

Comment: They are the up and down arrow buttons of the `<input type="number"/>` element. They are _not_ the up and down arrow keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="51" value="1" onkeydown="return false"; />
```

but you have to check the value on server side, anyway!

Comment: if he means "with keyboard up and down arrows" I'd rather use a function instead of the return false; so he can check if the key pressed is either up or down, if not then he returns false

Comment: He said "up and down arrow buttons" not "keys". I'm pretty sure he means the arrows of the `type="number"`field. Anyway U have a point: with function he can check more precisely the user interaction, but function is not pain less to test over all devices (including mobile).

Comment: totally agree on that!

Answer (score 0):

You can call preventDefault on keypress unless it's the arrow keys:

```
var numInput = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

numInput.addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode !== 38 && event.keyCode !== 40) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1L9hgd8m/1/) to demonstrate. If you don't care about the arrow keys on the keyboard, then you can omit that part of the check and just preventDefault on any keypress.

Answer (score 0):

event.preventDefault is a costly operation compared to return so [jsbin_example](http://jsbin.com/rileki/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="51" value="1"/>



      $("input").on("keydown",function update(event)
{
   var keyCod,
   srcObj = event.src||event.originalTarget||event.target;
   if(event.keycode || event.which)
      {
         keyCod = event.keycode || event.which;
      }
      else
     {
        keyCod = event;
     }
     if(!(keyCod  == 38 || keyCod  == 40))
     {
         return false;

      }
  console.log('after false');
      if(keyCod == 38)
      {
         srcObj.value = parseInt(srcObj.value)+1;
      }
      if(keyCod == 40)
      {
         srcObj.value = parseInt(srcObj.value)-1;
      }
});
```

Comment: except return false doesn't work unless it's in a jQuery event handler